# Strongloop: Change Default 200 Response to 202 in Generated Swagger Doc

Tags: javascript, swagger, strongloop

I've just started working with Strongloop, and I'd like to change the response in the Swagger generated doc to say 202, instead of the default 200.

[image]

Note that there's no problem changing the actual response code that is returned.  We can do this in the model, using the remoteMethod:

```
http: {verb: 'post', path: '/:listingId/fastTransfer', status: 202 }
```

It's the Swagger doc that I am having trouble changing.  I've been looking into the javascript code, and I can see where this is referenced (see route-helper.js).

```
var responseMessages = [
  {
    code: route.returns && route.returns.length ? 200 : 204,
    message: 'Request was successful',
    responseModel: returns.model || prepareDataType(returns.type)
  }
];
```

There should be some configuration change that I could make so that I should not have to change this file.  Does anyone know what needs to be added and where to change the default 200 response to, say, a 202?

Comment: What's your reasoning behind wanting to change it, out of curiosity?

Comment: The method is asynchronous, thus the proper response should be a 202 Accepted.  I can add specific error codes. Can we change the default 200?

Comment: Also, when there is no content in the response body, it will automatically tell us a 204.  It seems that it should be able to be configurable.

Comment: Just a comment, but 202 should only come into play if the request was accepted, but not completed yet. But I see what you mean in swagger, explicitly returning either 200 or 204.

Comment: Yeah 202 is the correct response for an asynch request.